# Como consigo colocar um valor opcional nessa condição?

Tags: adobe-flex

Como consigo colocar um valor opcional nessa condição?

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, regionDidChangeAnimated animated: Bool) {

    if var annotations = mapView.annotations {
        for annotation in annotations  {
            if let a = annotation as? MKPointAnnotation {
                encontrarEnderecoPara(a)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]